RPC response has invalid length of -16777216
I am trying to set up a Single Node Cluster(Hadoop).
But it seems that I can't type any command.
No matter what I type it always reply back like this
user@MSI:~/Downloads/hadoop-3.4.0$ bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir input
mkdir: RPC response has invalid length of -16777216
user@MSI:~/Downloads/hadoop-3.4.0$ bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop/*.xml input
put: RPC response has invalid length of -16777216

However, when I run bin/hdfs namenode -format it works fine.
If anyone knows what are the possible reasons that cause this problem, could you please guide me.

Could be a misconfigured server value in core-site.xml or hdfs-site.xml
